# Receiving cell phone emails through MS Exchange 2007

Tags: exchange-2007, cellular, pictures

I am encountering a strange problem whit receiving cell phone emails via my MS Exchange 2007.

When my customer needs to send me a picture of a container he/she takes a photo with a cellphone and then tries to send that to my email (name@domain.com). I can see the email in my inbox but I do not see the picture. The sender email address is in this format: xxxxxxxxx@mms.att.net

I have placed that email into my White List but still no luck. When I asked my customer to send it to my personal email (personal@hotmail.com) I can retrieve the email along with the picture.

What would prevent me from seeing those pictures?

Comment: I suggest to turn on higher logging level for Exchange Transport and check why the picture is getting stripped.

Answer (score 0):

Couple things:

Does it display in webmail in exchange?

By White List do you mean safe senders list in outlook?

Also I would guess that it is the encoding of the email.  Try embedding the picture in an email to yourself, or from a gmail account and see if it comes through.  If it does it's probably the encoding of the attachment.

Comment: By White List in the MS Exchange. I know if I try sending an email from xxxxxxxx@msg.telus.com it will work. But then it's my co-worker's phone with Outlook on it.